# Update record ADODB Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, excel-2003

I need to update single record in .mdb by using ADODB I can read but can't update...

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim OknoPodmiany
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim sciezka As String
sciezka = "c:\baza_danych.mdb"
Set cnn = New Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
cnn.Open sciezka
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst.ActiveConnection = cnn
rst.Source = "SELECT * FROM TBKlienci ORDER BY Nazwaklienta"
rst.Open , , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
i = 1
While Not rst.EOF
For j = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
  'ActiveSheet.Cells(1 + i, j) = rst.Fields(j - 1)   
    If Not ActiveSheet.Cells(1 + i, j) = rst.Fields(j - 1) Then
    Select Case MsgBox("Czy chesz zmienić:" & Chr(10) & rst.Fields(j - 1) & Chr(10) & "na:" & Chr(10) & ActiveSheet.Cells(1 + i, j), vbYesNoCancel)
        Case vbYes
           MsgBox "podmieniam"
           rst!Update.Fields(j - 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(1 + i, j)
        Case vbNo
           MsgBox "niepodmieniam"
           ActiveSheet.Cells(1 + i, j) = rst.Fields(j - 1)
        Case vbCancel
            MsgBox "anulowano"
    End Select
    End If
Next j
rst.MoveNext
i = i + 1
Wend
```

Problem is `rst!Update.Fields(j - 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(1 + i, j)` how may I pass it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Update method on your recordset for the changes to take effect.

```
rst.Fields(j - 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(1 + i, j)
rst.Update
rst.MoveNext
```